# Red icon for automounted disk / partition in nautilus (why?)

Tags: mount, nautilus, icons, disk, automount

i've recently reinstalled ubuntu a few times because i had issues with nvidia drivers.
But after a recent reinstall, i now have a red icon in nautilus for a partition i enabled automount for via the disk utility (ext4, part of the same ssd /home is on).
I couldn't actually find anything on the net about this issue.

I tried running fsck and it reported no error. I can access its content just fine. The mount point directory is owned by my user. The mount options are the default the disk utility suggested (and according to the internet, nothing special).
In the journal, relating to this i only have tracker-miner errors for which i also couldn't find a lot, only other users reporting about it where the answers seem to suggest it's nothing major.

On Ubuntu 22.04 with all available updates installed.
What could be the issue here, or how can i find out why it's displayed like this?

[Screenshot of Disk/Partition Icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGRgr.png)

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. I don't understand fully what the problem is. But I say this, the partition you made in the old system is not yours in the newly installed system. You should take control of the old partitions by `chown`.

Comment: The mount directory (/mnt/Work in my case) is owned by my user. In the disk utility ui there also is an option for the partition named 'become owner' (loosely translated), which i also already used. Is there another location i would need to check?

Comment: Could you paste `Disk` utility window for the partition? Or try to add the partition to `fstab` and `mount` it manually.

Comment: It seems the disk utility automatically creates fstab entries. This is what it set:
`/dev/disk/by-uuid/6371b54c-241e-4fb0-9118-95c1ebbb7198 /mnt/Work ext4 nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show,x-gvfs-name=Work,x-gvfs-icon=Work,x-gvfs-symbolic-icon=Work 0 0`

Comment: Oh, wow, now that i pasted this whole line in here, i realize that those parameters actually say 'x-gvfx-'icon'. I dismissed those as being similar to the other one that i did look up a while ago that just makes the drive show up under a certain name.I must have just misunderstood the options, as in german 'symbol' (in disk utility) could be understood as 'symbolic link', as well as 'icon'.
-And removing those entries, indeed makes it display as expected. Thanks for nudging me towards finding out my own mistake.

Comment: Case closed, post your own answer to answer section, it is allowed to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that i misunderstood the translation of the extra input fields the gnome disk utility has.
They resulted in the generated fstab entry containing 'x-gvfs-icon=[input dependent],x-gvfs-symbolic-icon=[input dependent]', which as the naming *in english* implies, overrides the icon (and my input didn't map to any valid one).